# Dynamic Routing from Public data.json file in React

Tags: reactjs, json, routes, dynamic, mapping

I am trying to implement dynamic routing using data stored in a data.json file stored inside my public folder in a React project. The idea is to create a Airbnb-style site where a user could view a dedicated page for each property. I'm only trying to implement this using static data stored locally and not a database.

My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to pass the id parameter into my fetch url similar to this...
`const { data } = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)`

And I'm not sure if there is a different or better way to achieve the desired outcome. I am able to implement 'useParams' to get the parameter, but I'm not sure how to match that to the fetch of the json data and load the json item dynamically.

Any help is very much appreciated!

I have tried adding it to the , attempted to add the ${property.id} to the end of the data.json fetch url, and no luck.

Here is my code:

data.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "House 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "House 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "House 3"
  }
]
```

App.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Rentals from "./pages/rentals/Rentals";
import RentalPage from "./pages/rentalPage/RentalPage";


import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigation />}>
            <Route path="rentals" element={<Rentals />} />
            <Route path="rentals/:id" element={<RentalPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Rentals.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Rentals = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch("/data.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (myJson) {
        setData(myJson);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((property) => (
        <div key={property.id}>
          <h2>{property.name}</h2>
          <Link to={`/rentals/${property.id}`}>BOOK NOW</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Rentals;
```

RentalPage.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const RentalPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch("/data.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (myJson) {
        setProperties(myJson);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  
  return (
{/* how to get this page to load the right object from data.json? */}
<h1>{property.name}</h1>)
};

export default RentalPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template Literals in RentalPage.jsx to create dynamic link. Instead of single quote, we use backticks to create the string.

```
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
})
```

You can read more about Template Literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I had tried that but I wasn't sure how to use template literals with my data.json file since it's in the Public folder and not pulling from a typical endpoint. Is there a way to do it with this sort of fetch?

    fetch("/data.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })

Comment: Getting particular object from the json file wont be possible. What you can do is first just fetch the "/data.json" file and then filter the particular object based on the id.